# Converting titelcase string dict to uppercase string text

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, string-formatting, uppercase

When attempting to reformat `{r[Name]}` to uppercase (originally it is titlecase: `James`)

#### Original code

```
string = 'text {r[Name]} data'.format(r=row)
```

#### Attempt

```
string = 'text {r[Name].uppercase()} data'.format(r=row)
```

I get the traceback: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'uppercase'`

Any ideas? Many thanks SMNALLY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because strings don't have a method named `uppercase`, exactly as the error message says.

You probably wanted [`upper`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper).

However, you can't actually call methods in a format string this way. You can access the `upper` attribute (just remove the parens), but then you'll get something like `'text <built-in method upper of str object at 0x12345678> data'`, which isn't very helpful.

So, how *do* you do this? You don't. `format` is intentionally restricted to make it harder to accidentally run arbitrary untrusted code. If you think you need a function call, that's usually a sign that you're getting too fancy and should just create an intermediate value explicitly. For example:

```
string = 'text {name} data'.format(name=row['Name'].upper())
```

Comment: Trying that returns the following: `text <built-in method upper of str object at 0x045ED440> data`

Comment: @SMNALLY: Which is exactly what the answer says will happen.

Comment: It does now, not when I originally commented however. Anyways thanks for the answer it works perfectly.

Comment: I think I am right in saying only people who have commented on this answer, or the OP gets notifications if you then  comment on it. Not random downvoters ?